# Visits per day stuck at 0 - Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed

Why isn't the visits-per-day counter for our site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106955/quantum-computing) working?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308966/349720).

It *is* fixed for site analytics as of some date no later than the 25th May. This has apparently also fixed the underlying issue on Area 51 but it apparently takes a while to update, so we'll need to give that some more time.

To satisfy people's curiosity, we've been averaging around 750 views per day over the past month or so, which is a **huge improvement** over the previous month.

**Update:** the stats on Area 51 are now working properly again!

Comment: What was the visit-count last month?

Comment: I'd need to write an SEDE query to get the exact number (assuming you can get that on SEDE) but it's increased by about 150%